# lambdas and attributes in c#

Tags: attributes, lambda, c#-4.0

Can you use a lambda expressions as an argument to an attribute? The motivation I am thinking of would be to eliminate reliance on magic strings

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is a compiler error specification that handles this:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Answer (score 2):

I wish but it does not seem as though you can.

You can encapsulate what you want in a type and reference the type, though.

```
public interface Accessor
{
  object GetValue(object source);
}

public class ExpressionDrivenAccessor<T, U> : Accessor
{
  private readonly Func<T, U> getIt;

  protected ExpressionDrivenAccessor(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
  {
    getIt = expression.Compile();
  }

  public object GetValue(object source)
  {
    return getIt((T)source);
  }
}

public class SomeAccessor : ExpressionDrivenAccessor<X, Y>
{
  public SomeAccessor() : base(t => t.SomeProperty) { }
}

[MyAttribute(typeof(SomeAccessor))]
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx

Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the following types:

`Simple types` (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)

`string`

`System.Type`

`enums`

`object` (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)

`One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types`

Comment: That reference is for C# 1.1, btw - not C# 4 (although it's still valid info, unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Attributes only accept certain compile-time constants.